# CO2 and CH4 calculations

Tags: environment, animal-by-products

I would like to get the following information.

The information was

The amount of:

- CO2 (carbon dioxide)
- CH4 (methane)

Produced in

- humans
- cattle

taking an adult animal as a reference

through the

- mouth
- digestive system

These are

2 x 2 x 2 = 8, useful figures, which I would like to compare and contrast in a pie chart to view the contributions of each individual to carbon emissions (and their relative contribution to the ozone layer hole problem).

I would also know what the percentage of carbon emissions due to humans and cattle (and other animals, including pigs, chicken, and fish, as well as others in a single category, is, when compared to carbon emissions due to other things (what else is there, I assume, just factories. If not, please add).

When I talk about carbon emissions, I am taking about both CH4 and CO2, and I would like to know, if O3 (ozone), is the problem under attack, how this reacts chemically with CO2 and CH4, and, how much each, by volume, contributes to the damage in percentage of volume of CO2 and volume of CH4.

Note, some of you may want in your answer to do

(amount produced by a human) * (number of humans) + (amount produced by cattle) * (number of cattle) + (amounts produced by chicken) * (number of chicken) + ...

To obtain total emissions for both of CO2 and CH4.

Comment: CO2 and CH4 emissions have little relation to the ozone layer issue you refer to. Stratospheric ozone was depleted primarily by chlorofluorocarbons (CFCs) which were used for refrigeration (for example) due to their stability. It turned out that when exposed to UV light in the stratosphere, CFCs broke down and destroyed ozone (which protects us by blocking out a lot of UV light from the Sun). The problem was eventually recognized and CFCs were widely phased out and replaced with other chemicals. Gradually, the ozone layer has recovered.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So I guess CO2 and CH4 emissions have more to do with the greenhouse effect (and, thus, global warming). Is this so? Thanks.

Comment: that is correct :) and unfortunately we haven't managed to solve that problem yet